# Dynamically opening modal with different content on button click

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular2-template

i am trying to develop angular2 application. I have 9 buttons in each of the card footers on a page. Clicking on any button or anchor tag should open the modal of bootstrap but it has to have different content for every click. The template for modal has to be the same except the content has to be different for every button clicked. Right now the modal opens on every button with the same template and content. How to associate ID with button so that click results in same modal template but different content.

Here's my code in sample.component.html

```
           <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-header-orange">
                       <h1 class="card-heading">Card Header Blue</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-p">
                            There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour,
                            or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there
                            isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.

                        </p>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                  <button (click)="openModal(template)" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</button>
                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-header-orange">
                       <h1 class="card-heading">Card Header Blue</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-p">
                            There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour,
                            or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there
                            isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.

                        </p>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                  <button (click)="openModal(template)" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</button>
                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


      <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-header-orange">
                       <h1 class="card-heading">Card Header Blue</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-p">
                            There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.    
                        </p>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                     <button (click)="openModal(template)" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my modal template:

```
      <ng-template #template>
     <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
       <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close"   (click)="modalRef.hide()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
   </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
This is a modal.
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try out the ng-content feature. You can use it as reference:- https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

If you use ng-content to dynamically change the content of the modal body, then your modal would look something like this:-

modal.component.html :-

```
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close-modal" (click)="closeModal()">x</span>
        <ng-content select="[modal-header]"></ng-content>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-content-container">
        <br>
        <br>
        <ng-content select="[modal-body]"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="overlay" (click)="closeModal()"></div>
```

and the call to the modal component should be like:-

abc.component.html:-

```
<modal >
<div modal-header>
    <h3>Instance</h3>
</div>
<div modal-body>
    "Your Template"
</div>
```

This is one way or else you could also use another way which is of dynamic component loader, which is more of a pro way to code. You can check for reference here:- https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Using component loader, we can dynamically load any component template into modal according to options.

If you opt to use the component loader then your modal would like :-

```
<div class="modal">

<div class="modal-dialog" *ngIf="(selectors$ | async).state">

    <div class="modal-header">
         <span class="close-modal" (click)="closeModal()">x</span> 
    </div>

    <div class="modal-content-container">
         <ng-container component-loader [config]="selectors.component" [payload]="selectors.data"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-overlay" (click)="closeModal()" *ngIf="(selectors$ | async).state"></div>
```

in this component loader is the directive which dynamically load different component according to the input recieved. The modal.component.ts file would be like:-

@Component({
        selector: 'modal',
        templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
   })

export class ModalComponent{
       @Input selectors: Observable;
       constructor( )
   }

The selectors would be an object like this :-
selectors = {
component: "Name of the component to be dynamically loaded",
data: "Any data to be passed to the dynamically loaded component as input"
}

Comment: by dynamically change the content i mean that instead of creating 10 modals for each button i should have one modal and depending upon the button clicked it should that content in modal. so how do you get which button is clicked and we call that component ?

Comment: Yes you can achieve that with the dynamic component loader. Every time you click on the button , you could just pass the component name to be loaded as an input to the modal, and then you can use the component loader to load the component( which would basically the body of the modal)

Comment: I have updated my answer with component loader explanation